# where is Fragment Caching in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want use Fragment Caching in my app ,so I write a test in `home/index.slim` in development mode:

```
-cache @dmeo do
  h1 hello wold
```

But I can't find the cache file in `tmp/cache`.

and I have set `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Now I don't know whether the Fragment Caching work,where the cache file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app config tells Rails **how** to cache things, via the `cache_store` option.  Whole pages are cached to disk but fragments are by default cached in memory.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores

if you want everything in tmp/cache try setting

```
config.cache_store = :file_store, "tmp/cache"
```

I haven't tried this myself but according to the docs it looks like it would work.

Comment: Display the current time, like <%= Time.now %>. If it doesn't change when you reload the page, it's been cached.

Comment: Have you restarted your server after changing the config?  What is the instance variable `@dmeo`?  What happens if you just have `-cache do` then `h1 The time is  #{Time.now}`

Comment: `-chache do` will raise `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Comment: I was going off this - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html   Which version of rails are you using?